# html table breaks background when resizing

Tags: html, html-table, background, tailwind-css

I'm using a tailwind table on max-width. For the html I'm using a default Laravel Jetstream layout.

When I try to use the scrollbar on smaller devices the background won't repeat in the browser.

[image: Table breaks background]

[image: Css]

Comment: Do you have a link? it will be a lot easier to troubleshoot that way

Answer (score 0):

This case has been solved by adding the overflow-x css property to the div surrounding the table.

**tailwind example:**

```
<div class="overflow-x-scroll">
<table class="min-w-full">
<!-- table content --> 
</table>
</div>
```